# Private multiplayer in Titanfall 2 PS4?

Tags: ps4, titanfall-2

We bought Titanfall 2 for PS4 simply to play a multiplayer free for all between family members. We're three, so there would only be three players in the game and would be trying to kill each other.

How does one do that? We tried a few things, and most of the time, we see other unknown players playing with us. Also, it seems that the game puts us in teams, so since we're three it's always 2 vs 1.

We just want to play free-for-all between three people.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no free for all mode and also you don't gain XP or progress toward challenges by playing Private matches. Sorry